# What is the quickest way to check that the random string I've generated hasn't been generated by me before?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm curious as to how places like [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4oDp.jpg) (which identifies each image by a unique 5 digit pin) carry this out. Clearly, one would have at the least an `O(n)` solution (or at best `O(n log (n))`depending on the algorithm), but since I'm expecting `n` to be millions, this is going to be an infeasible solution.

Comment: Maybe the strings aren't random. Maybe it's like a counter, and the string is a mapping from the numeric representation.  That way you're guaranteed uniqueness, just like if you listed out the numbers from 1 to 10,000,000.

Comment: To prevent downvotes for a lack of research effort, you should briefly explain the algorithms for the running times you mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

imgur most likely uses an "autonumber" primary key in a database.  The numbers in such a key are guaranteed to be unique; they get assigned in sequential order, and never get reused (even if the record they identify has been deleted).

You can munge these numbers to look any way you like, including the alphanumeric combinations that imgur uses.  One way is to use a [base 36 encoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) which, for the number 12345678, will return

```
7CLZI
```

It's easy to do in Javascript:

```
(1234567890).toString(36)  // => "kf12oi"
parseInt("kf12oi",36) // => 1234567890
```

although most likely you will be doing these conversions on the server, not in the browser.

[base58](http://fileit.in/p/131), will get you uppercase and lowercase letters, and numbers:

```
15FsU
```

**See Also**
http://convertxy.com/index.php/numberbases/

Answer (score 2):

You could use a sequential numeric key and then transform it using a [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/). Then, [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode it to get your string.

Nice thing is that recovering the key is easy enough: base 64 decode, do the multiplicative inverse again, and you have the key.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter. This is a very efficient algorithm. It does have the downside of a small amount of false positives.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if I've got the right end of the stick here but assuming you want to generate a random string and then store it to access something you'd just need to check if it is in your store.

If you had a SQL db table with a unique index on the string you could just try an insert. If the insert fails due to a repeated unique key you'd know you'd used it. It would be almost instant.